# Java Keytool CSR error even when keystore exists

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, truststore

I would like to securely exchange data between my own servers and these will not leave the internal domain. For this, I would like to:

1. Generate keys for keystore.
2. Generate a CSR using Keytool, specify the key above.
3. Import the response into my default `cacerts` file so that I can refer to that as my truststore.

So:

1. First I generated keypair using the following (default Encryption algorithm):

`keytool -genkeypair -alias mykeys -keystore mykeystore.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keysize 1024 -noprompt`

2. Then, I create a CSR using the following command:

`keytool -certreq -alias myinternalcert -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass changeit -file myinternalcert.csr`

It throws the following error:

`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <myinternalcert> does not exist`

I tried to seek examples in Oracle's blog and looks like this is the way to correctly generate a CSR - but for my case it's all errors :)

The only thing i understand about the SSL so far is:

1. Keystore - I want to authenticate myself to another server/client and my private key is in my keystore. I will also use this to sign my certificates.
2. Trust store - this is to determine whether the information the information I am receiving is from a legit source i.e. do I trust them. I store certificates here.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use the same alias when creating the CSR and importing the signed certificate that you used when generating the keypair.
2. You should import the signed-certificate response into your *keystore.* Not your truststore. You don't *trust* the signed certificate, you *own* it, and it therefore belongs in your *keystore*. Your *truststore* is for *other* certificates that you trust.

Comment: since I am using it within my own servers (i.e. not exposed to external services) I can just use the keystore `mykeystore.jks` also as my trust store? After I've imported the signed certificate? In essence, "I only trust this certificate when exchaging info between my own servers"

Comment: There are good reasons why you should always use separate keystore and truststore files.

Answer (score -1):

Okay - My own fault.

Actually the `alias` is the same alias created for `keystore`. [thanks to this post on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-keytool-essentials-working-with-java-keystores)

The `keytool -certreq -help` doesn't really print out clear information:

Options:

```
 -alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process (should have been "Alias of the keystore entry being used")
 -sigalg <sigalg>                signature algorithm name
 -file <filename>                output file name
 -keypass <arg>                  key password
 -keystore <keystore>            keystore name
 -dname <dname>                  distinguished name
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
 -v                              verbose output
 -protected                      password through protected mechanism
```

Comment: It should not be 'alias of the keystore being used'. Keystores don't have aliases. Keystore *entries* have aliases. It should be 'alias of the entry to process', as it already says, where the 'entry to process' is the alias of the keypair you want to generate a CSR for. This seems rather obvious.

Comment: @EJP           Not really - "Alias name of the entry to process" - What entry? Entry for this current CSR or entry for Public Private Key Pair Entry? Or something else? Keytool documentation is quite old and needs revamping a bit - that's all. The messages should be slightly less cryptic and there's no harm in that.